# How to iterate over a dataframe.info() in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert all the object variables in a dataframe to string.

Below is a sample

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['India','US','NZ'],
              'B':['ND','DC','WL'],
              'C':[1,2,3]})
```

df.info() gives

```
#   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   A       3 non-null      object
 1   B       3 non-null      object
 2   C       3 non-null      int64
```

Imagine having 100+ columns. Now I want to create a for loop to do something like below:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
lbl = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

df['A'] = lbl.fit_transform(df['A'].astype(str))
```

Comment: Your question is very confusing. What does this have to do with `.info()`? You can access the columns in a dataframe with `df.columns` if you're trying to loop through the columns, and you can use `astype()` without any loop at all

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I am not trying to loop through the calls. I'm trying to change the dtype of "object" columns to "str" or "int32" as needed using the labelencoder.

Comment: df.select_dtypes(include='object') just gives the data which has "object" type columns. I am looking to change the dtype of those columns to int or str

Answer (score 2):

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['India','US','NZ'],
  2               'B':['ND','DC','WL'],
  3               'C':[1,2,3]})

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   A       3 non-null      object
 1   B       3 non-null      object
 2   C       3 non-null      int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 200.0+ bytes

>>> list(df.select_dtypes('object'))
['A', 'B']

>>> df[list(df.select_dtypes('object'))] = df[list(df.select_dtypes('object'))].astype('string')

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   A       3 non-null      string
 1   B       3 non-null      string
 2   C       3 non-null      int64
dtypes: int64(1), string(2)
memory usage: 200.0 bytes
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select columns according to their data type, you can use `select_dtypes()` function:

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['object']) # will give you object data type
print(df)

       A    B
0   India   ND
1   US      DC
2   NZ      WL
```

You can use `include` or `exclude` parameters to exclude or include some data types, see detailed explanation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)

If you want to extract `object` type and convert to `string` you can do following:

```
lst = list(df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns)
df[lst] = df[lst].astype('string') 
df.info()

#   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   A       3 non-null      string
 1   B       3 non-null      string
 2   C       3 non-null      int64 
dtypes: int64(1), string(2)
```

If you want to extract `int` type and convert to `int32` you can do following:

```
lst = list(df.select_dtypes(include=['int']).columns)
df[lst] = df[lst].astype('int32') 
df.info()

#   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   A       3 non-null      object
 1   B       3 non-null      object
 2   C       3 non-null      int32 
dtypes: int32(1), object(2)
```

Comment: Thank You, while I came here for information on .info() processing, your answer was crystal clear and helpful in the future. Thanks!!